# Angular 2 Quickstart App Throwing Errors

Tags: angular

When I run the code from "5 MIN QUICKSTART" https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Here is the code I'm running and the npm-debub.log https://gist.github.com/140173804bb527b5ed20

file structure:

```
2angular/
   tsconfig.json
   package.json
   index.html
   app/
      app.components.ts
      boot.ts
```

Do anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Get both your ts files inside of an `app` folder or change the `System` configuration to not look for them in there:

`System.import('app/boot')`

And make sure you are running `npm install` before `npm start`

Comment: both .ts files are in an app folder. 

the structure is as shown in the 5 MIN QUICKSTART tutorial

I ran npm install, the problem persists.

Comment: well you might want to upload your example as is, otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: the gist link in the original post is the code that I am running, the example, as it currently is.

Comment: But the structure is not, you would be surpised how many people were just missing a folder. You obviously have something different than their example otherwise it would work for you, If you don't show the real thing we are merely guessing.

Comment: no those are the files.... I uploaded them to gist from the command line with the gist client. 

http://imgur.com/nTjkroh

Comment: @Casey what I'm trying to say is that your problem might not be with the contents of your files but your project structure. Your best bet to get help in this issue is to upload the whole project as is (with the same structure and all, not just all files separated), or create some plunker or code pen where you reproduce the issue.

Comment: yes i understood that you are saying that, the first time. But as I've told you, and provided a screen shot of the app structure as it is on my machine, the folder structure is as described in the 5 MIN QUICKSTART

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but changing the index.html from:

```
<script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

to:

```
<script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

fixed the problem.

the revised html was taken from take from: http://plnkr.co/edit/6MQ5sv6gR7nrhajiMgPU?p=preview

Comment: Your issue was that typescript compiler (tsc) wasn't running so your ts files weren't getting converted into `js` files. This change only tells the browser to grab the `ts` files instead of the `js` ones and compile/transpile them himself, which will happen for each file every time they enter your page, this is obviously not how you would do it in production, you want to compile them once before shipping them and server the client your js files, not your source code ( ts files )

Comment: so where/how do I tell the typescript compiler to run?

Comment: you can call the typescipt compiler which is installed as (tsc) or the scripts in your `package.json` do that for you when you do `npm start`

Comment: In my package.json scripts is "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" " and I've been using the npm start the whole time. So the typescript compiler (tsc) was running?

Comment: if you are getting the js files yes

Comment: so it was the index.html that was the problem...?

Comment: Once again.... if you don't upload your project as is, I don't know what the problem is, if your structure is just as you have it in the question, you are missing the `.js` files and that will cause the code with the onfiguration in the quickstart not to work.

Comment: Specify what exact error are you getting or why you say it doesn't work. If you start the server, open the app in a browser and click F12 you'll see a console with some errors.